# ng-change on number input for validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, input, numbers

I have a number input where I set the `min` and `max` dynamically based on another form field.  My scenarios are as follows:

- Level 1: Min = 2, Max = 50
- Level 2: Min = 5, Max = 1000

I have a `ng-change` event set up on the input field, to evaluate if the number follows my rules for each level.  If the number is either too high or too low, I set it to the minimum.

```
<input type="number" step="1" ng-change="isValid()" ng-model="level.num" min="{{minNum}}" max="{{maxNum}}">

$scope.isValid = function () {
    if( ($scope.level.num > $scope.maxNum) || ($scope.level.nums < $scope.minNum)) {
        $scope.tooMany = true;
        $scope.level.num = $scope.minNum;
    }
};
```

My Problem is that lets say I have selected Level 1 and want to enter `15`, as soon as I enter `1` it automatically changes my number to 2.  How can I only change the number when the user has full finished entering their input.

Comment: Why not using ng-blur? (instead of ng-change or for 1 digit input handling) @user1876246

Comment: On the ng-change I have it also making a calculation with the result shown to the user that I want updated in real time

Comment: You can use same function - in the end you want to prevent 1 as input only if it blurred out of the input @user1876246 I'll try to share code if you like the idea

Comment: @BenDiamant I think I know what your getting at, but I would be very happy if you would share some code!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is to apply blur as your change factor for min-number enforcment, because it's can be a standard usecase if your min-set is 3 and the input is 24 etc. this way you can encapsulate in 1 function and still maintain the logic

```
<input type="number" step="1" ng-blur="isValid(true)" ng-change="isValid(false)" ng-model="level.num" min="{{minNum}}" max="{{maxNum}}">

$scope.isValid = function (blurMode) {  
    if( ($scope.level.num > $scope.maxNum) || ($scope.level.nums < $scope.minNum && blurMode)) {
        $scope.tooMany = true;
        $scope.level.num = $scope.minNum;
    }
};
```

Comment: @user1876246 any result?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular 1.3 maybe you can use ng-model-options: [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wLzxKErm4x9AbHniEoSP?p=preview)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
```